# Open files depending on the value of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I am giving leave policy in loop now I want to open different files depending on the type of the leave resides in database.

**Blade.php**

```
<tbody id="myTable">
       <tr class="tr">
        <td class="text-center">{{ $leaves->id }}</td>
        <td  id="policy"><span class="leave">
        {{ $leaves->leave_policy }}</span>                                    
        </td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="check()" class="attachment-icon-pdf mr-5"> 
        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>

        </tr>
  </tbody>
  @endforeach
  </table>
```

**Script**

```
   <script>
    function check() {

            var val = document.getElementById('policy');
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input').each(function() {
                if($(this).attr("leave") == 'urgent') {
                    window.open('\\.\\tms\\tms-live\\public\\files\\1522061207.LeavesPolicy.pdf','mywindow')
                }
                else if($(this).attr("leave") == 'medical') {
                    window.open('\\.\\tms\\tms-live\\public\\files\\1522061207.LeavesPolicy.pdf','mywindow')
                }
                else if($(this).attr("class") == 'wedding') {
                    window.open('\\.\\tms\\tms-live\\public\\files\\1522061207.LeavesPolicy.pdf','mywindow')
                }
            });
        }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is `check()` function definition.  `id="policy"` is in loop?

Comment: check updated question

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: files are not being opened

Comment: In your function `this` is pointing to the window object.  Where is attribute `leave`, since `attr("leave")`.  `find('input')` where is `input`. Please add all related code.

Comment: 'leave' is declared in span inside 'td' with id 'policy'

Answer (score 1):

What i understand is, you need to open related document as per the policy clicked.

- Pass policy name to the check function in template. `onclick="check({{ $leaves->leave_policy }})"`.
- check function

  `function check(_policyName) {
     if(_policyName == 'urgent'){
        window.open('urgetRelated.pdf')
     }
    if(_policyName == 'medical'){  // Second condition
        window.open('medicalRelated.pdf')
     }
    ...
   // Other conditions
    ...
  }`

Comment: Nope nothing happened.